# batch script coming terminating if XCOPY is not able find a file

Tags: scripting, batch-file

With reference to the following code snippet

```
xcopy D:\CBS_Upgrade\CBS2.2_DEV_B%CBSBuild%\DDLs-Lending Database\CBS-Upgrade\DDLs-Lending /S
```

I wanted to find out why the script is terminating and is not executing commands after that?
Is there any way to fix it?

I know the file will not be there, but I wanted the script to go on to the next commands.

The message shown by `xcopy` is

```
File not found - DDLs-Lending
0 File(s) Copied.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to use the `/c` switch, which instructs the `xcopy` command to ignore any errors. The full documentation for the `xcopy` command is available [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx).

But [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9630291/366904) is right, batch files will continue executing, regardless of whether an individual command contained therein fails. So I'm not entirely sure what the problem you're trying to solve is.

Answer (score 2):

A batch file will continue even if a command fails. If you just want to suppress error output, then you can append `2>nul` to the command.

Answer (score 2):

Batch files will terminate under windows if certain complex operations (such as piping) are being performed.  For instance, the following command will terminate a batch file if `awk` does not exist:

```
awk -? | find "*****"
echo never gets here
```